# how to prove: every two numbers gcd can be divided by this two numbers any common divisor

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

for example, I have two numbers: 36 and 48. their gcd is 12. 12 can be divided by any common divisors of these two numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12. Is there a general proof for this? Thanks!

Comment: It can be proved building the gcd with prime factorization.

Comment: You can find the standard proof in the linked dupe. It works by showing that the gcd has linear form $\,\gcd(a,b) = ja+kb\,$ which makes it clear that $\,c\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\,c\mid \gcd(a,b).\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\gcd(m,n) = d$.  Then $m= d*m'$ and $n=d*n'$ for some integers $m',n'$.

Now if $m', n'$ had any factor  in common (other than $1$), and we called that factor $f$, then $f*d$ would be a common divisor that is larger then $d=\gcd(m,n)$.  So we can safely conclude $m',n'$ (the remains as it were) have no factors in common[$*$].

If $a$ is a common factor of $m$ and $n$ it can not share any factors (other than $1$) with either $m'$ nor $n'$ as $m',n'$ have no factors (other than $1$) in common.

Now $a|m$ so $\frac ma = \frac {dm'}a = k$ is an integer. $\frac na = \frac {dn'}a = j$ is an integer.  If $a\not \mid d$ then $a $ will have factors that do not divide $d$ and must therefore divide $m'$ and $n'$.  But $m'$ and $n'$ have no factors in common.

That's it.

[$*$] Note, it would be a mistake to conclude that $m'$ and/or $n'$ will have no factors in common with $d = \gcd(m,n)$ or with $a$.  It is possible that *one* of $m'$ or $n'$ will have some factors in common with $d$ or with $a$. but it is impossible that *both* $m'$ and $n'$ will have factors in common.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now :) but I think it should state: "m|a" and "d∤a" instead of "a|m" and "a∤d". isn't "|" same as "/" (division slash)?

Comment: No.  In fact they are almost opposites.  $a|d $ means "a divides into d".  Such as $5|15$ means 5 divides into 15.  $\frac ad $ means the number you get when you divide a by d.  So $\frac 5 {15}=\frac 13$.  We know: $a|d \iff \frac da$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Claim: If $a\vert b$ and $b\vert c$, then $a\vert c$.

Proof: $c=kb=k(ma)=(km)a$.

Comment: It seems you misread the question, which I read as $\, c\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid \gcd(a,b).\ $ The above does not work for that.

Comment: It would seem so.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $d=\gcd(a,b)$ is that it is the positive generator of the ideal $(a,b)\subset\mathbf Z$.

So there exist integers $u,v$ such that $ua+vb=d$. Now if $c$ divides both $a$ and $b$, we can write $a=ca'$, $b=cb'$ -$a',b'\in\mathbf Z$. We deduce at once
$$d=uca'+vcb'=c(ua'+vb').$$